# skvideo + ffmpeg: Can't set path to binaries

Tags: python, ffmpeg, scikits

For some reason, setting the path to the ffmpeg binaries doesn't work completely.

While it seems like this works like it should:

```
import skvideo.io
import skvideo.datasets

ffmpeg_path = "C:/Users/xyz/ffmpeg-4.3.1-win64-static/bin/"
skvideo.setFFmpegPath(ffmpeg_path)
print("FFmpeg path: {}".format(skvideo.getFFmpegPath()))
print("FFmpeg version: {}".format(skvideo.getFFmpegVersion()))

>>> FFmpeg path: C:/Users/xyz/ffmpeg-4.3.1-win64-static/bin/
>>> FFmpeg version: b'4'.b'3'.b'1'
```

Running these lines directly after does not:

```
videodata = skvideo.io.vread(skvideo.datasets.bigbuckbunny())
print(videodata.shape)

[...]
>>> File "C:\Users\xyz\Anaconda3\envs\cv_env\lib\site-packages\skvideo\io\io.py", line 133, in vread
  assert _HAS_FFMPEG, "Cannot find installation of real FFmpeg (which comes with ffprobe)."
>>> AssertionError: Cannot find installation of real FFmpeg (which comes with ffprobe).
```

Can't figure out, why it's not set correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to some hidden comment in the official [scikit-video repo](https://github.com/scikit-video/scikit-video/issues/140).
Apparently you have to set the path and **then** import the package again:

```
import skvideo

ffmpeg_path = "C:/Users/xyz/ffmpeg-4.3.1-win64-static/bin/"
skvideo.setFFmpegPath(ffmpeg_path)

import skvideo.datasets
import skvideo.io

print("FFmpeg path: {}".format(skvideo.getFFmpegPath()))
print("FFmpeg version: {}".format(skvideo.getFFmpegVersion()))

videodata = skvideo.io.vread(skvideo.datasets.bigbuckbunny())
print(videodata.shape)

>>> FFmpeg path: C:/Users/xyz/ffmpeg-4.3.1-win64-static/bin/
>>> FFmpeg version: b'4'.b'3'.b'1'
>>> (132, 720, 1280, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu also does not comes with `ffmpeg`. As mentioned by @fukiburi, once `ffmpeg` (which mostly acts as a independent binary,nothing to deal with python or `skvideo` python package itself) is downloaded using `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`, it makes default installation of `ffmpeg`, `ffprobe`, `ffplay` etc in `/usr/bin/`, which in turn solves the problem.